# c++ structured bindings: What is the standard order of destruction?

Tags: c++, c++17

Is there any definition of the order of destruction of objects returned from a method that can be put into a structured binding statement? cppreference doesn't seem to mention destruction order, and a quick test on godbolt reveals something other than what I expected.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

struct A{
    A()=default;
    ~A(){ std::cout << "~A()" << std::endl; }
};

struct B{
    B()=default;
    ~B(){ std::cout << "~B()" << std::endl; }

};

struct C{
    C()=default;
    ~C(){ std::cout << "~C()" << std::endl; }
};

auto MakeStuff()
{
    auto a = A{};
    auto b = B{};
    auto c = C{};
    
    return std::make_tuple(std::move(c), std::move(b), std::move(a));
}

int main()
{
    auto&& [c, b, a] = MakeStuff();
    std::cout << "Results now: " << std::endl;
}
```

Results:

```
Program returned: 0
~C()
~B()
~A()
Results now: 
~C()
~B()
~A()
```

I guess structured binding constructs the objects in the [brackets] from right to left, seeing as how the destructors invoked as `c` first, then `b`, then `a`. Is this standard behavior, or am I relying on something implementation-specific here?

Thank you.

Comment: A structured binding doesn't create N separate objects. `[c, b, a]` is a single variable (reference to a tuple), and `c`, `b`, `a` are (somewhat magical) references bound to its subobjects.

Comment: Very close to UB I think as `return std::make_tuple(std::move(c), std::move(b), std::move(a));` create a tuple of references which then go out of scope, making `auto&& [c, b, a] = MakeStuff();` create dangling references.  It's not UB only because the references aren't used.

Comment: @RichardCritten `std::make_tuple` decays the arguments and stores them by-value. It never results in a tuple containing references. (That would happen with `std::forward_as_tuple`.)

Comment: @user17732522 ...unless arguments are wrapped into `std::reference_wrapper`.

Comment: Doesn't it create an unitialized tupple of `c`, `b` and `a` in `main()` and passes that as structure return value to `MakeStuff` and `make_tuple` constructs the elements in-place?

Comment: @Evg ok, yes, but a `reference_wrapper` isn't really a reference and the same exception would apply to any class with a reference member.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Not sure what you mean exactly, but there is only one tuple object created, a temporary materialized from the prvalue result of `make_tuple` and `MakeStuff`. So the tuple is technically constructed in `main`. The elements of the tuple are in-place constructed from the arguments to `std::make_tuple` in the tuple constructor. That this is achieved by passing a pointer to the uninitialized memory for the tuple to the functions is an implementation detail.

Comment: @user17732522 That's exactly what I said. One tuple created in `main`, initialized in `std::make_tuple` and elided in `MakeStuff`.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Ah, ok. I wasn't sure whether this was an actual question or a rhetorical one.

Comment: @user17732522 Most of that even gets optimized away if you inline `MakeStuff` and only one thing is left of the tuple: `call std::_Tuple_impl<0ul, C, B, A>::~_Tuple_impl() [base object destructor]`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Structured binding changes absolutely nothing about the language in terms of order of construction/destruction. Structured binding is a fiction, a linguistic shorthand that turns `get<I>(unnamed_object)` or `unnamed_object.some_name` into `some_name`. In this fiction, `unnamed_object` is the *actual object* which is generated by the expression and captured by the `auto[]` structured binding declaration.

That object works exactly like any other C++ object. The order of subobject declarations in the class (if it is a class) determines the order of construction and destruction, just like any other C++ object.

Now, when it comes to `std::tuple`, the order of its subobject declaration is *unspecified*; it is allowed to vary from implementation to implementation. Again, structured binding has nothing to do with that. So the order of destruction can be whatever your particular implementation wants it to be.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is this behavior spelled out as implementation-dependent in the standard? Or is this just a hole in the standard that is not addressed as of this moment?

Comment: @Teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeej There are some standard library implementations out there which store `std::tuple` elements in the order of the template arguments and there are some that store them in reverse order. So it doesn't seem likely that to me that this will ever be standardized, since it would force a `std::tuple` ABI break for one of these. The program should not rely on the order. If you want a specific order, you can use a custom aggregate class instead. They also work with structured bindings. This way you can choose the order.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

I did some digging and it looks like at the very least the WG has this issue on an active issues list.

See link for details: https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2528